# How to set "Tap to click" on guest accounts in macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, trackpad, system-settings, preferences, guest-account

I setup new MacBooks with macOS Mojave having the "Tap to click" setting on in Trackpad settings. However, when a guest user logs in, this isn't set. Almost all other Trackpad settings are the same as the initial Admin user, except the "Tap to click."

Is there a way to make the "Tap to click" setting the default for guest users?